# My animated hamburger menu isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

I have been creating this app for a project at school and I am just trying to get my head around jQuery. I found quite a good example [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Hamburger-Button-Transition-Effect-with-jQuery-CSS3.html).
Which I have been trying to embed and use as a menu button for my slider. 
I am having trouble getting the animation to play on click.

It seems to play when I run the code, but then it's not after; it also seems as though it is missing some elements.

Here is my code, its linked to a CSS file as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Volo - X</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Blueprint: Slide and Push Menus" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="sliding menu, pushing menu, navigation, responsive, menu, css, jquery" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
        <link href="STYLE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body class="cbp-spmenu-push">
        <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">
        <p>
        </p>

<body onclick="myFunction()">        

            <div id="numberOne">                
            <img src="PHOTOS/menu.png"style="height:20px">
            </div>                            

            <div id="marginIncrease">
            <a href="index.html">My Account</a>
                </div>  
            <a href="Post A Job.html">Jobs</a>        
            <a href="Help.html">Help</a>
            <a href="About - X.html"> About - X</a>   
            <div id="Facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
            <img src="PHOTOS/Facebook.png"style="height:40px">
            </a>

  </div>          

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var trigger = $('#hamburger'),
isClosed = true;

trigger.click(function () {
  burgerTime();
});

function burgerTime() {
  if (isClosed == true) {
  trigger.removeClass('is-open');
  trigger.addClass('is-closed');
  isClosed = false;
  } else {
  trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
  trigger.addClass('is-open');
  isClosed = true;
  }
}

});
</script>

            <script>
            function myFunction() {
            showLeft.onclick("myfuntion").disabled = true;
            }
            </script>   

                </nav>

                <div class="container">
                <header class="clearfix">
                <p>

                </span>


                <div id="logo"

                <h1><img src="PHOTOS/Volo x.png"style="max-width: 40%"></h1>

                </div>

                <nav>

                </header>
                <div class="main">
                <section>
                    <h2> </h2>

                    <!-- BUTTON GOES IN HERE FOR TOP MENU
                    <button id="showLeft"></button>
                     -->
                    <button id="showLeft"></button>

                        <b>
                        <p style="line-height:2.5">
                        <font size="5" color="#939597">
                        // MY ACCOUNT
                       </p>
                        </font>
                        </b>                                    
                        <p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <b>NAME:</b> 
                        </font>
                         Matthew Arnott                       
                        <p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <b>ADDRESS: </font>
                        </b> 205 Galloway Street, HAMILTON
                        <p>

                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <b>PHONE: </font></b> 021 938 737
                        <p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <b>EMAIL: </font></b> mat3tarnott@xtra.co.nz                        <p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <b>BALANCE:</b> </font>
                        $109.45
                        <p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <b>STATS: </font></b>31 Jobs Completed, 99% Positive Feedback
                        <p>
                        Last Payed at 2:33pm, 14th April 2015
                        <p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <b>MESSAGES:</font>
                        <font size="3" color="#000">
                        <a href="OPEN CHAT"> ( 1 )</a>
                        </font>

                        </p>
                        <p style="line-height:2.5">
                        <font size="5" color="#939597">
                        // CURRENT JOBS
                        </font>
                        <p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        DRIVER LAST UPDATED: </font> 2:00PM, 1/4/15<p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <img src="PHOTOS/location.png"style="height:15px">     LOCATION: </font> Hamilton, Waikato<p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        COST OF JOB:</font> $120
                        <p>
                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        JOB NUMBER</font>  <a href="JOB INFO"> # 4397</a> 
                        <p>

                        <font size="3" color="#F7941D">
                        <a href="OPEN CHAT">MESSAGE DRIVER</a>

                        </font>
                        </p>

</body>                        

  <div id="hamburger" class="hamburglar is-open">
  <div class="burger-icon">
    <div class="burger-container"> <span class="burger-bun-top"></span> <span class="burger-filling"></span> <span class="burger-bun-bot"></span> </div>
  </div>

  <!-- svg ring containter -->
  <div class="burger-ring"> <svg class="svg-ring">
    <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4" d="M 34 2 C 16.3 2 2 16.3 2 34 s 14.3 32 32 32 s 32 -14.3 32 -32 S 51.7 2 34 2" />
    </svg> </div>
  <!-- the masked path that animates the fill to the ring --> 

  <svg width="0" height="0">
  <mask id="mask">
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4" d="M 34 2 c 11.6 0 21.8 6.2 27.4 15.5 c 2.9 4.8 5 16.5 -9.4 16.5 h -4" />
  </mask>
  </svg>
  <div class="path-burger">
    <div class="animate-path">
      <div class="path-rotation"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="buttonset">

                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
        <script>
            var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),

                body = document.body;

            showLeft.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showLeft' );
            };



            function disableOther( button ) {
                if( button !== 'showLeft' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showLeft, 'disabled' );
                }

            }
        </script>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m22!1m12!1m3!1d100916.33952065148!2d175.26492379999996!3d-37.7751415!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m7!1i0!3e0!4m0!4m3!3m2!1d-37.792778399999996!2d175.2717903!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snz!4v1429932205297" width="100%" height="300px" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>

                        <p>
                        <style type="text/css">
                         p { margin-left:1em;}
                        </style>
                        <font size="1" color="#939597">
                        Copyright © 2015 Volo - X, All Rights Reserved
                        </font>
                        <p>

    </body>

</html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all you have set HTML structure proper. You have two body why? Then start Script end script and again start script. This not good way to write script.  http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: What grade did you get Matthew?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is malformed, which may well be the issue. You have 2 body tags, the nav element starts inside one of them and finishes in the other, just 2 of the issues I can see. I would recommend stripping the page back to a basic structure and putting the code back in one by one. Your basic HTML format should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <!-- scripts and css -->
   </head>
   <body>
     <!-- HTML elements -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Also, scripts and css should be in external .js and .css files where possible, rather than inline, for better maintainability

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<div id="logo"` without the closing `>` caracter, try to see if it is that.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise understanding the basics before manipulating the DOM in anyway. I almost *threw up* when reading that.